# How to solve npm install but permission deny?

Tags: npm, vuejs2, laravel-5.5

I am using Laravel 5.5 with vue.js.

I did try `chmod -R 777 node_modules`

I run `npm install` then chmod again.

I still cannot bypass this error.

[image]

Comment: post your `index.js` file

Comment: @parthu_panther sorry for the lack of info. I am using laravel 5.5 and vue.js. do u mean u want to see the app.js?

Comment: try with `sudo npm install`

Comment: already in `sudo su`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo npm install
```

This will solve the permission issue.